# Xamarin.Forms DisplayAlert - duplicated title in Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to display an alert in my Xamarin.Forms project using the following code:

```
DisplayAlert("¡Oops!", "Nos es imposible ubicarte, intenta ubicarte manualmente", "Ok");
```

In iOS it works all OK, but in the Android emulator I see a duplicated title. Please see the below image

Is this behavior normal? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Normal behavior, no.... what version of Xamarin.Forms are you using and what API level is the emulator running?

Comment: The emulator is running the API lvl 23. My current Xamarin.Forms version is: 2.3.3.193

Comment: DisplayAlert is using AlertDialog.Builder on Android, do not see how the "double title" can happen.... at least not from this code:  https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/e6d5186c8acbf37b877c7ca3c77a378352a3743d/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/FormsApplicationActivity.cs#L253

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes... I can't see why this is happening. I will test it in a device and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Oops :D!

My bad. I'm using the Grial UI Kit for Xamarin.Forms... hence here's the solution:

https://github.com/UXDivers/Grial-UI-Kit-Support/issues/75

Answer (score 1):

Clear Solution->Delete obj and bin directories in all the project folders->Rebuild Droid project->Check if it works as it should

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried your proposed solution but the issue remains.